# Is Vue 3 backwards compatible with Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

In different posts around the internet (for example [this one](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/function-apis/active-rfcs/0000-function-api.md)) I found that Vue 2 code should work with Vue 3 but for me it does not. For example I have simple component

```
<template>
    <div class="overflow-x-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow overflow-y-auto relative">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-left">
                    <th>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </th>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="1">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td> <span>{{ id }}</span> </td>
                    <td> <span>Cort</span> </td>
                    <td> <span>Tosh</span> </td>
                    <td> <span>{{ email }}</span> </td>
                    <td> <span>Male</span> </td>
                    <td> <span>327-626-5542</span> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id: 1,
            email: 'test@mail.com'
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        alert('mounted');
    },

    created() {
        alert('created');
    }
};
</script>
```

The table is generated just fine, but both `mounted` and `created` not fired when component made. Also the `email` and `id` not shown. Only the table is shown.

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#breaking-changes

Comment: Yes, Vue 3 is backward compatible with Vue 2 using options API. There are some life-cycle naming changes such as https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#beforeunmount

Answer (score 2):

Your code works:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      email: 'test@mail.com'
    }
  },
  created() {
    alert('created')
  },
  mounted() {
    alert('mounted')
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

  <div id="app" class="overflow-x-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow overflow-y-auto relative">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr class="text-left">
                  <th>
                      <label>
                          <input type="checkbox">
                      </label>
                  </th>
                  <th>User ID</th>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Gender</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="1">
                      </label>
                  </td>
                  <td> <span>{{ id }}</span> </td>
                  <td> <span>Cort</span> </td>
                  <td> <span>Tosh</span> </td>
                  <td> <span>{{ email }}</span> </td>
                  <td> <span>Male</span> </td>
                  <td> <span>327-626-5542</span> </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't. The code I provided is in stand-alone component file

Comment: It should not make any difference. A component is only crucial for readability/code management. I can't understand your situation at the moment.